# How can I measure the reverse leakage value of a TVS diode?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, multimeter, protection, tvs

Compared to the component's datasheet without protection circuit, for quality control purposes. Can I use a multimeter for that?

Comment: A TVS is a Zener diode but with a larger die to handle transient power pulses. If you want to measure its leakage current, you have to reverse-bias it with a voltage-source via a series resistance and monitor the current until the component avalanches. The only thing you can do with a multi-meter is measure the diode forward drop in \$V_f\$-mode.

Comment: Thank you. But I still have some question. Why I need a series resitance for that ?, Could I connect directly voltage source with reverse bias diode. And if so, what device could help me measure the leakage current.

Comment: Well, technically you could avoid the resistance but the source must then be current-limited (say 1-2 mA) because when the TVS avalanches, it offers a sharp knee characteristic and its dynamic resistance is very small. If you can efficiently limit the current on the source, it is a way to go also.

Comment: The best tool for measuring this kind of characteristic is a curve tracer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_curve_tracer -- see also https://circuitcellar.com/research-design-hub/create-your-own-i-v-curve-tracer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your multimeter in ammeter mode to measure the current directly. If you are just verifying the reverse leakage spec from the datasheet, then you will not have avalanche conditions (unless the part is defective).

Another option is to put a small resistor in series with the diode. For example if the leakage current is 100uA at 15V, you could use a 1k resistor in series. Use your multimeter to measure the voltage across the resistor. Use Ohm's law (V=IR) to calculate the current. A 1k resistor will give you 0.1V with 100uA. Ideally you would have a second multimeter to measure the diode voltage by itself. But as long as your resistor is small enough the voltage drop won't matter too much.